# Block the other buttons after one button was pressed

Tags: android

In my activity I have many buttons that launch other activities. The problem is that when I press a button I don't want to be able to press another, and so to launch 2 activities (or more). What is the best solution to block the other views (buttons) after one of them was pressed?

Comment: If only one of the buttons should be selected at a time, why cant you think of using RadioWidget?

Comment: It's not just about buttons (it could also be a listview or something else). It's about blocking the views after launching a new activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one `onClickListener()` for all buttons. In listener switch the actions as per id.

```
public .. onClickListener(){
// Disable all buttons here..
button1.setDisabled(true);
button2.setDisabled(true);
button3.setDisabled(true);
...
switch(view.getId()){
 case R.id.button1:
// Start some activiy ... or do some task...
break;
 case R.id.button2:
...
break;. ...

}
```

**Don't forget to enable all buttons in `onResume()`**

```
public .. onResume(){
button1.setDisabled(true);
    button2.setDisabled(true);
    button3.setDisabled(true);
}
```

**OR, Try This to enable/disable all views in a viewGroup...**

```
private void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);

    if ( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;

        for ( int idx = 0 ; idx < group.getChildCount() ; idx++ ) {
            enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Pass the `view` parameter as the parent layout containing all buttons.

I haven't used this, but this should work. Try playing around this code.

Comment: Isn't there a more general approach for this? One I could use for listviews also. Like disabling the whole layout or smoething.

Comment: @Gratzi, you can write a method which goes through all the child views of layout (getChildren() method) and set them disable.

Comment: The layout is complicated. And it's not that easy to search it. It would be easier to lock the whole layout (if that would be possible)

Answer (score 2):

Just in each of your onClickListener for each button make `button.setDisable(true);`.
Don't forget to enable them in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to disable the Buttons

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```